# Whcih type of load sensor should i use to calculate weight placed in a shopping cart

Tags: sensor, load-cell

I wish to calculate the load inside a shopping cart and i am confused on which type of load cell/sensor should i use. Assuming weight from (0-50 kg). 
This sensor is to be interfaced with Arduino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely want to use load cells.  I'm not sure of your setup, so I can't suggest how many load cells you need.  Most electronic weigh scales for weighing people have 4 load cells, one per foot.

A load cell generally looks like a wheatstone bridge.  It has an excitation supply and ground terminal and *two* output pins.  These pins are differential: as one pin is going up, the other is going down.  However, the change in output signal is quite small - usually only a couple of percent of your excitation voltage for a full-scale weight change.  You use a differential amplifier to subtract the signals from each other so that all you see is the change in load-cell output.  You need a diff amp for each load cell in your system.

Now that you have your individual load cell signals, you need to add them together so as to get the total weight.  You can do this in the analog domain by using an op-amp configured as a summing amplifier *or* you can do it in your controller.  The difference is how many analog inputs your controller has to have.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to place a "dead" Wiiboard on the bottom of the cart, and screw a piece of plywood on top of the Wiiboard. The "dead" Wiiboards go for next to nothing on eBay. Usually they have good strain gage sensors. Get two just in case one of the strain-gaged beams was damaged.

You can likely reuse the signal conditioning electronics on the interface board - cut the traces for digital signals and attach them to Arduino. You'll also need to provide the 3V and GND. The A/D chips they use are labeled and there are datasheets available for them. I don't recall offhand what chips in particular are they, though.

I pretty much buy Wiiboards just for the instrumented beams they contain. Even if you buy a new one at Walmart, it's still cheaper than buying individual sensors!